# Access decryption key from remote location

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, security

I am saving my sensitive information in mysql database.

My application is hibernate and spring. I am using http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html to

encrypt data. As per examples I keep the key I use to decript in Spring.xml.

Now I need to keep this "key" in a remote server outside my application server and provide VPN.

What are the suitable approaches to access the key from Financial application ? Do you

recommend to pull the key from Key server to my application server?

Comment: May be you can use webservice to retrive key or directly servlet to get key which will be reside on other server outside of your application server.

Comment: Jasypt use salt(Random by default , fixed) and password to encrypt in the case of making the salt dynamic how the internal decryption take in to place.